# 2004 Nissan Altima manifold exhaust bolts

Tags: nissan, stuck-bolt, altima

My dad and I were trying to take off the manifold on our Nissan and the bolts will not budge. We don't have the money to do it and we need it done because we don't have any other car. We tried spraying it, my dad broke a tool and I got cut badly on my thumb. Is there any possible way we can get it off and any ways how? Please don't say take it in because we don't have money.

Comment: These are the bolts (or nuts) which attach the exhaust manifold to the engine? Or where the exhaust pipe attaches to the manifold? What lubricant have you tried using?

Comment: manifold to the engine, and kroil to lubricate it.